# laravel связать таблицы

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

есть таблица users
я создал миграцию на таблицу usersattributes, которая содержит информацию о пользователе, подскажите теперь контроллер нужно создавать для usersattributes ? и как их связать?

Comment: https://toster.ru/q/506803

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы создаете миграцию, в ней создаете таблицу. В зависимости от того какая связь(1:1, 1:М, М:М) связываете таблицы. Скорее всего у вас будет связь 1:1.
Значит можете в миграции для таблицы **usersattributes** не указывать **increments('id')**, а вместо этого создать в ней поле user_id и связать их один к одному.

```
 $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
 $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Выйдет что-то подобное.

Далее в моделях прописываете связи

Модель User:

```
public function attributes()
{
    return $this->hasOne(UserProfile::class);
}
```

Модель Attributes:

```
 public function user()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
 }
```

Comment: а контроллер нужно создавать?

Comment: Если он Вам нужен - создавайте. А вообще не обязательно.

Comment: @Aslero почитайте побольше про MVC, поскольку явно видно, что Вы не понимаете, что такое контроллер, а что такое модель.

Comment: а что значит belongsTo?

Comment: Неужели проще спрашивать элементарные вещи, чем загуглить и прочитать все? https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/eloquent-relationships

Comment: еще вопрос, связь создали, а как выводить по связи?

Comment: разобрался Auth::user()->attributes->username

Answer (score 0):

будет так?

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('userattributes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('address');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Да, будет так. Можете добавить еще $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index(); вместо $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

Comment: а что это дает?

Comment: В двух словах: индекс ускоряет выборку по тем полям, к которым он применен. Более детально - читайте https://ruhighload.com/Индексы+в+mysql