# Как в Laravel использовать belongsTo hasMany в модели?

Tags: php, laravel

Знаю как работают relation-и в контроллере но как использовать их  в моделях где они объявлены ?

Comment: [ниже](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/877727/laravel-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B) есть похожий вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да как везде так и в моделе. Метод `getCommentsPosts` наглядно показывает.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    /**
     * Получите сообщение, которому принадлежит комментарий.
     */
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }

    public function getCommentsPosts()
    {
        $res = [];
        $comments = $this->all();
        foreach($comments as $comment)
        {
            // Допустим что у поста есть поле title
            $res[$comment->id] = $comment->post->title; // Вот так )
        }
        return $res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Чтобы не делать запрос в каждой итерации можно использовать [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading). Также есть удобный метод [mapWithKeys](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-mapwithkeys)

`return $this->with('post:title')->get()->mapWithKeys(function ($comment) {
    return [$comment->id => $comment->post->title];
});`